Find a maximal area of a convex figure whose all $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ shifts can make a full circle turn (current record is 0.8064846)
Problem. Consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Given a convex solid figure $\mathcal{P}$ such that $(0,0)\in\mathcal{P}$. For every pair $(n,m)$ of integers, let $\mathcal{P}_{n,m}$ be a shift of $\mathcal{P}$ with respect to a vector $(n,m)$. For a time parameter varying from $0$ to $1$, every figure $\mathcal{P}_{n,m}$ rotates around the point $(n,m)$ in the positive direction, each with its own non-negative speed, so that the following two conditions are satisfied:

Two distinct figures can intersect (touch) only at the boundary;

At the time moment $1$, every figure has made a full $360^{\circ}$ turn.


Find the maximal possible area of such $\mathcal{P}$.
The first construction. This problem occurred to me while working on the paper about defects and grain boundaries in tilings (the motivation comes from a study of $2D$ crystals), but it has an independent interest. The circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ is, naturally, such a figure. Surprisingly, the area of $\mathcal{P}$ can be larger than $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
Indeed, let $ r=\big{(}1+\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})\big{)}^{-1}$. Consider a circle (call it  $\mathcal{C}$) of radius $r$ and centered at $(0,0)$. Consider an octagon inscribed in $\mathcal{C}$, as shown on the right:  Let our $\mathcal{P}$ be made of this octagon with four circular segments of $\mathcal{C}$ added, as shown.
To the left of $\mathcal{P}$ we have $\mathcal{P}_{-1,0}$. The latter can make a full circle rotation, in the process just touching $\mathcal{P}$. This is due to the choice of $r$, since this yields $\mathrm{OH}+\mathrm{OA}=1$.
Suppose now that we have a copy of $\mathcal{P}$ centered at every point $(m,n)$, $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$: Those with $m+n$ even can make a full circle rotation. Afterwards, those with $m+n$ being odd can make a full circle rotation as well. The area of such $\mathcal{P}$ is equal to
$$\frac{2\pi+4\sqrt{2}}{6+\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}=0.8064733591_{+}>\frac{\pi}{4}=0.785398163_{+}.$$
Improvement. One can do even better. Let $X\in[0,\frac{1}{4}]$, and $r=\frac{1}{1+\cos(\pi X)}$. The following figure (shown here for $X=0.15$) also solves the problem:  Its area is equal to
$$\frac{2\sin(2\pi X)+\pi(1-4X)}{\big{(}1+\cos(\pi X)\big{)}^2}.$$
Surprisingly, the maximal value is achieved not for $X=\frac{1}{8}=0.125$, but $X_{0}=0.1266579725_{+}$, which is the solution to
$$\sin(\pi X)=\pi\Big{(}X-\frac{1}{4}\Big{)}.$$
Skipping all the calculations, we formulate the following
Proposition. Let $\vartheta$ be the unique solution to $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)=x$. Then the area of $\mathcal{P}$ can be as large as
$$\Theta=\frac{4\vartheta}{1+\sqrt{1-\vartheta^2}}=0.8064846301_{+}>0.8064733591_{+}.$$
Comments. We may assume that the boundary of a figure is piecewise smooth. The given solution employs a very simple  ("chess-like") rotation pattern. The problem itself can be altered in at least four ways:

The figure is non-convex;
The rotation is allowed also in the negative direction, so that the total rotation is still $+360^{\circ}$ for each figure;
Each $\mathcal{P}_{m,n}$ has an initial phase $\phi_{n,m}\in[0,2\pi]$;
There are only $N^{2}$ figures $\mathcal{P}_{m,n}$, $0\leq m,n\leq N-1$, for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

For example, if we consider non-convex case and $N=2$, then the constructed octagon-like $\mathcal{P}$ can be augmented with two more circular segments and non-convex parts. To find a rotation pattern for every piece so that all four eventually make a full turn is a simple puzzle:
One can further ask whether $N=3$ or $N=4$ already yield the same answer as $N=\infty$.
I do not know the full solution for the initial problem even in the simplest "chess-like" rotation pattern case. If somebody can find an improvement to $\Theta$ in any direction (more sophisticated convex figure and/or rotation scheme), that would be great! Since the center of rotation for each figure is fixed, and due to convexity, intuition suggests that this problem must be easier than, say, the Moving Sofa Problem.

Have you looked at a dodecagon or hexadecagon rather than an octagon? Does breaking up the rotation further improve the result?

Answering to the first question: yes, I have. This amounts to $X=\frac{1}{12}$ or $X=\frac{1}{16}$. Both give a better constant than $\frac{\pi}{4}$. But later I noticed that continuous $X$ works, too, and the maximal value is to the larger side of $\frac{1}{8}$, not the smaller.
